# Put a Jbutton On a Jbutton on java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;



public class ButtonOnButton extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton firstButton; // first Button
    private JButton secondButton; // second Button
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ButtonOnButton frame = new ButtonOnButton();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ButtonOnButton() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
         GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1,0); // the button is in entire screen now and i want to put the "secondButton" on this red button.
        contentPane.setLayout(gl);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        firstButton = new JButton(""); // 
        secondButton = new JButton("");
        firstButton.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("meeple.jpg"))); // disabled icon
        firstButton.setEnabled(false);
        secondButton.setBackground(Color.blue);
        
        contentPane.add(firstButton);
        firstButton.add(secondButton);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
// it work with button enabled, but diswork with button disabled and setDisabledIcon 
//sorry for my english bad i hope sincerly you understand( here decipher ).
    }

}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f02B9.png]

I want to put a Jbutton on a Jbutton
i.e The JButton is setEnabledFalse and have a DisabledIcon and has another button on top (in the link it is blue)

```
// I want to put a Jbutton on a Jbutton 
//  i.e The JButton is setEnabledFalse and have a DisabledIcon and has another button on top (in //the link it is blue)
```

Comment: I think you're over thinking the problem - why do you need compound buttons?  You could use an [`OverlayLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) to achieve the same thing, but again, I'd question the need to have buttons on top of buttons - it doesn't make for a very intuitive UX

Comment: Dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016161/how-to-put-a-jbutton-on-a-jbutton-disabled-with-icon-in-java-swing)

Comment: *it work with button enabled, but diswork with button disabled* - a clear question is important for a clear answer. "doesn't work" doesn't state the problem. Your topic heading is "put a JButton on a JButton" so I assumed the second button didn't show up. When I ran your code the Icon didn't even paint. Removing all the logic related to the second button and the Icon still didn't paint. So that is the real problem.

Comment: @camickr ok it's clear, yeah it was confused sorry really.

Comment: __do not__ delete and repost a question - instead edit the previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75016161/how-to-put-a-jbutton-on-a-jbutton-disabled-with-icon-in-java-swing to make it answerable

Comment: @kleopatra I tried for 30 minutes, but they said it was not possible to publish because there was too much code while I justified this code there

Comment: @kleopatra, In this case, I believe the OP did the correct response by reposting and deleting a question that had already been closed. People in this forum are very quick to close a question. But few will reread/reopen a question after the question has been improved. I tend to evaluate each situation. If the question was not closed, then I would have updated the original question because it will still give people an opportunity to answer. The OP made an honest effort to improve the question and hopefully will see that a proper question will yield good results in the future.

Comment: @camickr _People in this forum are very quick to close a question_ as they should: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close (aside: this site is not a forum as you know :) and _the OP did the correct response by reposting_ actually .. no: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance lists the OP's options, a repost is not amongst them.

Comment: wondering why the edit effort of the previous question failed, though - if you can post it here, editing the previous with the exact same content should have worked. As to the problem: still don't see what you _really_ want to achieve and why you considered _adding_ secondButton (that is, make it a child of) to firstButton - there's is not a single tutorial out in the wild (crossing fingers and hoping ;) that does so for whatever reason. Puzzled that the answer by @camickr solves your issue - making it smell like a xy-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a quirk of the button. In order to display a disabled icon you also need to provide the button with a regular icon.

In your example you only care about the disabled state so you can share the Icon:

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("meeple.jpg"));
    firstButton.setIcon(icon); 
    firstButton.setDisabledIcon(icon);
```

Comment: thanks  it works  but i dont know why we should use firstButton.setIcon(icon);  but np it work thanks bro @camickr

Comment: Well, I guess the assumption is why would you ever create a JButton that is always disabled? Normally you would be able to toggle the state of the button enabled/disabled, so you should also have an Icon for the normal state so the button functions correctly. However, the real question is why would you ever use a disabled button for something like this? As many people have commented adding a button to a button is a poor UI.